# video as background - multiple resize bugs it out

Tags: jquery, css, html

So I have this video tag, casual video tag with position fixed, top and left are set to 0px.

You can find the example here:
http://stvdd.com/video/

I have this little script:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#bgvideo').on("loadedmetadata", scaleVid);
            $(window).resize(function() {
                scaleVid();
            })

            function scaleVid(){
                if($(window).width()/$(window).height() > 1.7777777){

                    $('#bgvideo').css({
                        'width':$(window).width()
                    })
                }
                else
                    $('#bgvideo').css({
                        'height':$(window).height()
                    })
            }

        });
```

Here's the problem: when i resize just once or twice, it works. But when i resize really fast and just play with my window size, it bugs out.
The video res is 16:9, hence the 1.77777 (I want it to maintain proportion)

Comment: What do you mean by "it bugs out"?

Answer (score 1):

maybe the **resize event** is firing more than you want..

could be the **resize event bug** in some browsers that fires multiple times while your dragging:

http://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/

you could try a polyfill for the resize event by Paul Irish:

```
    (function($,sr){

      // debouncing function from John Hann
      // http://unscriptable.com/index.php/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/
      var debounce = function (func, threshold, execAsap) {
          var timeout;

          return function debounced () {
              var obj = this, args = arguments;
              function delayed () {
                  if (!execAsap)
                      func.apply(obj, args);
                  timeout = null;
              };

              if (timeout)
                  clearTimeout(timeout);
              else if (execAsap)
                  func.apply(obj, args);

              timeout = setTimeout(delayed, threshold || 100);
          };
      }
      // smartresize 
      jQuery.fn[sr] = function(fn){  return fn ? this.bind('resize', debounce(fn)) : this.trigger(sr); };

})(jQuery,'smartresize');
```

and then use like this:

```
// usage:
$(window).smartresize(function(){
     // code goes here
     scaleVid();
});
```

nice demo of its use:

**http://www.paulirish.com/demo/resize**